# Google Finance Historical Data with Multiple Attributes? (Dates, high, low, close,)

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I'm using this formula:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(GOOGLEFINANCE("NYSE:"&A4, "all",  DATE(2020,4,1), DATE(2020,4,30), "DAILY"), 2, 4)
```

I'm only getting one column for April 1, 2020.

I would like to get the full range April 1, 2020 - April 30, 2020.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the function to return only two rows (the header and the first day):

[image]

Replace the next-to-last argument (2) by a higher number and you're good to go:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(GOOGLEFINANCE("NYSE:"&A4, "all", DATE(2020,4,1), DATE(2020,4,30), "DAILY"), 30, 4)
```

[image]